# Question about Number Theoretic Function

Tags: number-theory

[image: See the picture for question]

I know how to prove (a). It is just $2^w(mn)=2^w  (m) \cdot 2^w (n)$.
However, for part (b), I can just write $n$ as 
$p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_r^{k_r}$,
or write d as this kind of form, but I do not know what to do next. Can anyone help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_r^{k_r}$ as you said, $r=\omega(n)$. Then
$$\tau(n^2)=\tau((p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_{\omega(n)}^{k_{\omega(n)}})^2)=\tau(p_1^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}\ldots p_{\omega(n)}^{2k_{\omega(n)}}),$$ so $$\tau (n^2)=(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)\ldots (2k_{\omega(n)}+1)=\sum _{i=0}^{\omega(n)}( \sum _{1\leq a_1<a_2<\ldots< a_i\leq \omega (n)}2^i\prod_{j=1}^ia_i).$$ So why that is the same as the RHS? think by the multiplication principle.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot